# How to estimate Mean with Uncertainty of a selected sample from variable A, that occured when variable B met some condition?

Tags: bootstrap, monte-carlo, measurement-error, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am trying to find the mean of a sample from time-series of variable 'A', consisting of all 'A' values that occured when the concurrent Variable 'B' met some condition.

I know that the A measurments have an uncertainty of ± 1.0 kph, and the B measurments have an uncertainty of ± 0.5 cm. I need to propogate this uncertainty across the two variables.

My idea is to take my time-series array, and adjust each A value by ± a random amount ≤ 1.0, and each B value by ± a random amount ≤ 0.5

I then select all rows in the "randomized" array where B meets the required condition, and calculate the mean of the associated A values

I repeat this process for 1000 or so iterations, and calculate the overall mean and standard deviation of the 1000 "means".

Is this a valid approach? Would this be considered a kind of Monte-Carlo simulation? Or bootstrapping?
Is there a better approach I should use to estimate the uncertainty?